# What is the gradation associated to a cocharacter of $GL_V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

[[J.S. Milne, Reductive Groups, March 10 2018, v2.00]](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/RG.pdf) at 22.10 uses the following definition which I do not understand:

Let $k$ be a field with $\operatorname{char}{(k)} = 0$, $V$ a vector space, $\lambda : \mathbb{G}_m \to \operatorname{GL}_V$ a homomorphism. Then there is a gradation $V = \bigoplus_i V_i$ of $V$ defined by $\lambda$.

*How is this gradation defined?*

By way of example, take $V = k^n$, $\lambda : \cases{\mathbb{G}_m \to \operatorname{GL}_V \\ t \mapsto \operatorname{diag}{(t, 1, \cdots, 1)}}.$ Then $V$ is naturally $V = \operatorname{span}_k{\{(1, 0, \cdots, 0)\}} \oplus \operatorname{span}_k{\{(0, 1, 0, \cdots, 0), \cdots\}},$ the "eigenspace" of $\lambda$ plus the remainder, but I am unsure if this is meant or how it would generalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, the algebraic group $\mathbb{G}_m$ has a $1$-dimensional representation $V_n$ where $z \in \mathbb{G}_m$ (over any particular commutative ring) acts as multiplication by $z^n$; said more invariantly, there is a standard $1$-dimensional representation $V_1$ given by the identity map $\mathbb{G}_m \to \mathbb{G}_m \cong GL_1$, and you can take tensor powers of this representation (with any integer exponent) to get $V_n \cong V_1^{\otimes n}$, where $V_{-1} \cong V_1^{\ast}$.

The category of representations of $\mathbb{G}_m$ (over a field of characteristic $0$ at least) is semisimple and these are the simple objects; that is, every representation of $\mathbb{G}_m$ is a direct sum of copies of $V_n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. An alternative way to describe this result is that an action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on a vector space (in the algebraic group sense) is exactly the same thing as a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading on it (in the sense that we have an equivalence of categories respecting the forgetful functor to $\text{Vect}$); this equivalence even respects the natural symmetric monoidal structures on each side.

In your example, $\text{span}(e_1)$ is the piece of the grading in degree $1$ and $\text{span}(e_2, \dots)$ is the piece of the grading in degree $0$.